# show html in auto complete jqueryUi

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i use jqueryui for search in my site just like facebook
jquery code:

```
//search main
function split( val ) {
    return val.split(  );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}
$( "#mainsearch" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
    $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( "/block/search.php", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
        }, response );
    },
    search: function() {
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
     focus: function() {
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        window.location.replace(ui.item.url);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
    }
});
```

php code:

```
while($f = mysqli_fetch_array($s,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if($userid != $f['id']){
        $name = $f['name'].' '.$f['family'];
        $url = $siteurl.$f['username'].'/';
        array_push($results, array('id' => $f['id'],'value' => $name,'url' => $url));
    }
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

but if i insert image tag like:

```
<img src='something'>
```

its just show < img > text not an image when its show result
there is anyway to solve it?
thank you

Comment: What does that auto-complete stuff have to do with the image?

Comment: what does the JSON returned look like? You can definitely do this but you might need a custom rendering function for the autocomplete.

Comment: Related: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-html-in-autocomplete

Comment: its just show text - if i put html its show that html as normal text - i want show user image in there too

Comment: Is the <img> tag is properly closed with the corresponding end tag </img> ?

Comment: no its just type it ! i mean i see <img> text not a image --- i think its convert html tags  to &lt; and &gt; symbols

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery-ui [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source): "If you want the label to be treated as html you can use [Scott González' html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/src/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js)".

Answer (score 0):

ok i solve this problem with code blow:

```
function split( val ) {

function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}
$( "#mainsearch" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( "/block/search.php", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
        }, response );
    },
    search: function() {
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
     focus: function() {
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        window.location.replace(ui.item.url);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
    }

})


 .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $( "<li style='clear:both'>" )
.append( "<a href='"+item.url+"' style='height:50px'><img style='float:right;height:50px;width:50px;vertical-align:middle;' src="+item.img+">"+item.value+"</a>")
.appendTo( ul );
};return val.split(  );
}
```

and php code:

```
while($f = mysqli_fetch_array($s,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if($userid != $f['id']){
        $name = $f['name'].' '.$f['family'];$img = getimagesizes($f['image'],50);
        $url = $siteurl.$f['username'].'/';
        array_push($results, array('id' => $f['id'],'img' => $img,'value' => $name,'url' => $url));
    }
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

.data must convert to html and show your result
as you can see in my qustion  example in jqueryui is completely diffrent with this
but with this you can put html in your auto complete :)